# Houdini Apprentice not showing icons

Tags: 11.10, icons

Houdini Apprentice is not showing icons. Anyone having this problem with Houdini installs on Ubuntu 11.10? Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the icons are converted from svg files by the tool
/opt/hfs11.1.67/hsvg/hsvg-real (your houdini version might be different)
and this tool depends on a different gtk version and some libraries
need to be an older version then the ones installed on your system.

Try starting houdini from a terminal to see the errors.

A solution is to copy the libraries from an older 11.04 installation:

- copy /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0 to /opt/hfs11.1.67/hsvg
- copy /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 /opt/hfs11.1.67/hsvg

DO NOT COPY these libraries directly in your system (that means do not overwrite the files in /usr/lib or /lib) but put them in the hsvg subfolder of your houdini installation otherwise your system might be broken.

If i remember correctly you also need to create some links for your system libraries:

```
$ cd /usr/lib

$ sudo ln -s libdirectfb-1.2.so.9 libdirectfb-1.2.so.0

$ sudo ln -s libfusion-1.2.so.9 libfusion-1.2.so.0

$ sudo ln -s libdirect-1.2.so.9 libdirect-1.2.so.0
```

and finally in a terminal do :

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/hfs11.1.67/hsvg
```

and start houdini from that terminal by:

```
$ cd /opt/hfs11.1.67

$ source houdini_setup_bash

$ houdini
```

The icons are cached and you probably only need to do this once.
After the icons are generated you can start houdini normally from
the gui launcher.